# How to create circular list in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I need to create a language list, some like Android date picker. I'm struggling with the rotation part. Is it possible to use [flat-list](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) to create some like this?

[image]

If anyone knows a way to do this or any third party-lib to achieve this task in both Android & IOS. please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use react-native-picker or react-native-wheel-picker.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-picker
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker